# "work with us" or "work for us"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

> I believe he has a great potential and I am happy to educate him as
> much as I can during the period when he works with us.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct? Do you have a better way to rephrase it?

Comment: "works with" and "works for" have different meanings. Are you his colleague or employer?

Comment: @StuartF I am his employer, but I work with him daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is correct and more successful as regards modesty. It can convey a more welcoming tone. "Work with someone" is not so focused on asserting hierarchy like "work for someone" which clearly states who the boss is  and who the subordinate.

*With* can bear the connotation of:

> working for, serving under, etc.
>
> - having been ***with*** the firm for 20 years ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/with))

So I think you would be safe using *with*, whether you are colleagues or boss and subordinate.

Comment: Proofreading is off-topic here so I will only post this variant in a comment: _I believe he has a great potential and I am happy to **train** him **to the best of my abilities** during the time he works with us._

Answer (score 0):

The above phrase 'work with us' is where the employer here refers that the person "working for him" is a deserving candidate and the employer is open to his mistakes and willing to guide him further and make him a better personality.
So "work for us" is the initial statement as employer is'nt aware of his abilities initially.